# How to run PHP editable in an iframe with JS?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, ace-editor

I created an HTML/JSS editor using [this tool](http://ace.c9.io/), which, when editing displays the result in an `<iframe>` (preview).

```
editor.getSession().addEventListener('change', function () {
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = editor.getSession().getValue(); // ex: '<div>Hi!</div>'
});
```

This is easy, the problem is with the PHP editor... obviously if I insert a PHP code in the `innerHTML` this can not be executed on the client side.

If value is:

```
<?php 
    $name= 'John Doe'; 
    echo $name; 
?>
```

This shows:

```
<!--?php $name= 'John Doe'; echo $name; ?-->
```

**What is the best way to save this temporary code and run instantly on the iframe (preview)?**

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> run instantly on the iframe (preview)

If you wanted the user edited php code to run and show output completely in the client side browser,

then there is no pragmatic way to do this.


Because, to run php codes,

***you need a php runtime at the first place.***


Now, whether the clients have php installed in their system(PC) or not,

you have no access to that via the browser.

Now if you are desperate to run the code( on your server then ) and send output to the clients browser,

then 

**WARNING**:: **It's highly dangerous**, 

taking string's from unknown(and hence untrusted) sources and 
running them as php code on the server, you can get your server hacked(and whacked) easily at a short time :p

because,
you don't know what code they are writing(unless you explicitly moderate it before running :p )


*(Now If you don't know what you are doing)*

you can use the **eval** construct as described here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
eval("?> $str <?php ");
```